# Computing Shortest Path Distance for multiple points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, network

I have been looking for ways on how to compute the shortest distance between one point to multiple points using a specific road network.

I have not been successful in achieving the solutions in this site.

Here's my case:

I have 3 shapefiles:
1. Road Network (lines)
2. Polygon Centroids
3. Source Point (Starting Point)

How do i easily compute the shortest distance between the starting point to the polygon centroids over the road network?

Answer (score 2):

I am doing a similar analysis and using the plugin QNEAT3 https://root676.github.io/ShortestPathAlgs.html. it works very well for the purpose. // Frida